# Precompiled user control crashes VS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, user-controls, crash

I have created a [precompiled user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx).  The basic steps are to create a Web Site project then publish to generate the DLL.

Then I created a Web Application project and added a reference to the DLL.  In my page I registered the DLL and was able to access the control as `<prefix:control_ascx ... />`.

If I run without debugging <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, everything works as expected.  If I run with debugging <kbd>F5</kbd> Visual Studio 2008 crashes.  I have the VS service pack installed: `Version 9.0.30729.1 SP`.  Any ideas how to fix this?

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  9.0.30729.1
  Application Timestamp:    488f2b50
  Fault Module Name:    MSVCR90.dll
  Fault Module Version: 9.0.30729.4974
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4b7a226f
  Exception Offset: 0003523b
  Exception Code:   c0000417
  Exception Data:   00000000
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 228d
  Additional Information 2: 228d061655d5d251935c240a855d1597
  Additional Information 3: a62e
  Additional Information 4: a62e597a147799b95fd60928a6816817
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project crashed Visual Studio.  It's a bug in VS, the exception code indicates that it is making a call to the C runtime library with an invalid argument.  That immediately terminates the program.

This is going to be difficult to deal with, the bug lives deep inside the VS codebase no doubt.  It is likely that it has something to do with your project but it is next to impossible to diagnose exactly what might be wrong with it.  You'll need some trained eyes to spot the potential mistake, if any.  If you don't have anybody inside your own company to do this for you, you can call Microsoft Support to get help.

They will need your project so they can repro the crash.  Best thing to do is the provide a minimum repro project, one that easily demonstrates the bug.  Have it ready to upload before you call, along with your credit card.  In the process of creating this repro project, you often discover the reason.

Comment: I can't get much simpler than I already have.  The UserControl has one Repeater control and is in an otherwise empty Web Site project.  The other is a default Web Application project, added reference, registered in page, and used in page.  I can try removing the repeater to simplify, but this is almost as simple as it gets.  I think before calling MS I would rather try this in VS 2010.  Thanks for your help.